# Constructing a Weighted Random Graph

Tags: networks, social-network

I want to create a weighted random graph (in contrast to the unweighted Erdős–Rényi model). I have a list of weights (derived from a real-world network, very skewed distribution that most weights are 1 and the rest of them are between 6-8). My plan is to first create a Erdős–Rényi model and randomly reassign the weights according to my list of weights. Does it sound like a right approach or my new network essentially lost the key characteristics of a random graph? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, and solve it the same way you do.

This is perfectly fine, in my opinion: we produce a uniformly sampled random graph in the class we are considering (graphs with given numbers of vertices and edges, and with given weights).